# Query for finding what are the reports has not been generated today but were generated yesterday?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query for

finding what are the reports has not been generated today but were generated yesterday.

I have tried this but this is not working.

```
select * from records where name not in 
(Select * from records where rdate to_date('26-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')) and 
and rdate=to_date('27-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

[SqlFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfea2)

I should get the output with the records `aa` and `dd`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Dont know which answer to accept as both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  records 
where 
  rdate=to_date('26-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') and 
  name not in (Select name from records where rdate=to_date('27-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

Comment: Syntax error is there; `not in` accepts only 1 column, but you specified `*` and query lacks `=` in sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

A `left outer join` is preferable to `not in` in cases like this:

```
select * from records r1
  left join records r2 on
    r1.name = r2.name and
    r2.rdate = to_date('27-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
  where r1.rdate = to_date('26-03-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') and r2.rdate is null
```

This finds all of the reports that were run yesterday, then joins reports that were run today.  Using `where r2.rdate is null` then *excludes* the rows that matched to a report today, so you are left with the ones that were run yesterday but not today.

This is much more efficient, because `not in` executes the subquery repeatedly, while this only executes one query.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfea2/25)